# DispatcherServlet causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name [default]

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets, illegalargumentexception

I'm getting the following error in my catalina.out log which appears to be preventing my servlet from loading:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name [default]
```

I believe my web.xml is set correctly with the servlet-name fields matching (see below).  Any information on how to further debug (I've read through the posted articles) would be appreciated.

```
    Web.xml
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
```

My Tomcat Version `8.5.35.0`

My Java Version `openjdk version "1.8.0_181", OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-2~deb9u1-b13),OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)`

The catalina.out log

```
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.241 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@3ddc8239] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.241 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@3ddc8239] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.241 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@64592113] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.242 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@64592113] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.242 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@64592113] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.242 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@64592113] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.242 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@64592113] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.242 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@1baba9aa] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.242 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@1baba9aa] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.282 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[/api-common-logging]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.283 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[/api-common-logging]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.283 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[/api-common-logging]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.298 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[/api-common-logging]] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.299 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[/api-common-logging]] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:49.451 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getDefaultWebXmlFragment No global web.xml found
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.443 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.444 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.444 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve[appServlet]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve[appServlet]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve[appServlet]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve[appServlet]] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve[appServlet]] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.445 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]]] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.446 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]]] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.446 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.446 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging].StandardWrapper[appServlet]] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.446 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging]] to [FAILED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.446 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name [default]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMappingDecoded(StandardContext.java:3184)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1370)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1184)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more

10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.448 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/api-common-logging.war]
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-common-logging]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.449 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/api-common-logging.war] has finished in [7,779] ms
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.451 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.451 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.452 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.456 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.456 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@6c1a657c] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.458 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@6c1a657c] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.458 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@6c1a657c] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.458 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@6c1a657c] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.458 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl@6c1a657c] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.458 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@19cb3998] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@19cb3998] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@19cb3998] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@44853097] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@44853097] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@44853097] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@44853097] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet@44853097] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@19cb3998] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.459 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@19cb3998] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.460 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.460 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.461 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.461 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[]] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.461 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [WebappLoader[]] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.561 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = hpdb_hrdb Ignoring unknown property: value of "ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer" for "jdbcInterceptors" property
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.561 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = hpdb_hrdb Ignoring unknown property: value of "35000" for "validationInterval" property
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.564 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = hrdb_seeker Ignoring unknown property: value of "ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer" for "jdbcInterceptors" property
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.565 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = hrdb_seeker Ignoring unknown property: value of "35000" for "validationInterval" property
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.569 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.569 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.569 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.569 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.569 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.569 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve[]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve[]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve[]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve[]] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve[]] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.571 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]] to [STARTED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.678 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[]] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.678 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[]] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.678 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager[]] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.679 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@1700a85e] to [INITIALIZING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.679 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@1700a85e] to [INITIALIZED]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.679 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@1700a85e] to [STARTING_PREP]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.744 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting state for [org.apache.catalina.util.StandardSessionIdGenerator@1700a85e] to [STARTING]
10-Nov-2018 17:49:56.744 FINE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal Setting sta
```

Comment: Somewhere (else) you have a `<servlet-mapping>` specifying `<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>`, but you don't have a servlet by that name.

Comment: Thanks Andreas - you are absolutely correct.  This web.xml had additional service-mapping sections with default instead of the servlet name.  Changing those to be consistent fixed the issue!

Comment: Eric / @Andreas: Could one of you consider creating an answer for this issue? It was a good question with no exact SO duplicate AFAIK, and I think it merits an accepted answer rather than just a comment for the solution. (And nice work for a first question.)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere (else) you have a `<servlet-mapping>` specifying `<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>`, but you don't have a servlet by that name.